# Do I need to add extra stream terminal operation to trigger Future task execution before calling Future::get

Tags: java, concurrency, java-stream

I have a simple function, and simple question:
Do I need the first `toList()`?

```java
Arrays.stream(items)
   // build task and submit to ExecutionService, 
   // which returns a Future
   .map(item -> executeTask(item)) //Stream<Future<Result>>

   // generate all the Futures, stash them in a collection, 
   // then wait for them to complete
   .toList() //List<Future<Result>>
   .stream() //Stream<Future<Result>>

   //wait for result
   .map(Future::get) //Stream<Result>
   .toList();
```

More details, the function

1. takes in an array of `items`
2. do some task on each `item` and submit the task to an `ExecutionService`, which returns a `Future` for each `item`
3. wait for the result for all `items` before returning the list of results

My friend argues that we need that extra `toList()` (after `.map(item -> executeTask(item)`) operation because

> Streams are lazily evaluated so the map() call isn't invoked until a terminal operation (toList()) is called.
> So we want to generate all the Futures, stash them in a collection, then wait for them to complete

But what I feel is that the function will work the same way even without that extra `toList()` since we already have a `toList()` after `.map(Future::get)`.
So is it really needed?

Comment: Streams process elements one by one, so if you didn't have that intermediate `toList()` then you'd be scheduling a task, waiting for it to complete, then scheduling the next task, waiting for _that_ task to complete, and so on (i.e., your code essentially becomes single-threaded). The intermediate `toList()` makes sure that all tasks are scheduled at once, and then you stream on the collection of `Future`s to wait for all of them to complete (though you might want to look into the `ExecutorService.invokeAll` methods).

Comment: thanks @Slaw I've written a short code and it proves you're right. Just wondering if this one by one mechanism is documented anywhere?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's documented explicitly, but you can infer it from the fact it's possible to short-circuit infinite streams. Otherwise, `Stream.generate(this::createTask).map(this::executeTask).findFirst();` would never complete.

Comment: It’s not specified in this way, because you should not rely on it. If an alternative Stream implementation finds a way to improve performance by processing two at a time, that would be fine.